# How can I output javascript to a view in asp.net mvc3?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-3

Good morning All,

I have a javascript variable in my view. I keep doing this...

```
 var skinData = null;
```

and then on document.ready....

```
 $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'theme/getskins',
                data: {},
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function(data){
                    skinData = data;
                }
        });
```

my question is why am I doing this on after the view has loaded.  I'm trying to do this in _ViewStart.cshtml

```
viewPage.ViewBag.SkinInfo = new JsonResult { Data = SkinManager.GetSkins() };
```

How can I take this value and output its value to my javascript variable.  I don't think I need to do another request when I really want to push this to the client on the first trip. Any tips or advice is of course appreciated.  How can I do this correctly?  I tried a few variations of this but it obvious isn't working. Stuff like...

```
  var skinData = @ViewBag.SkinInfo.Data;
```

This just outputs the namespace.  Any ideas how to do this correctly?

Cheers,
~ck in San Diego

Comment: What is `SkinManager.GetSkins()`, is it a .NET object, a string perhaps?

Comment: No, its a .NET DataContract class with properties

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will want to use some a serializer to convert your `.GetSkins()` method result into a json object. Either the built in JavaScriptSerializer or json.net

```
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
viewPage.ViewBag.SkinInfo = serializer.Serialize(SkinManager.GetSkins());
```

And then in your view

```
var skinData = @Html.Raw(ViewBag.SkinInfo);
```

Comment: this outputs it incorrectly. Using entities instead of quotes... var skinData = {&quot;CookieExpiration&quot;:3650,&quot;CookieName&quot;:& etc...

Comment: See update, try using @Html.Raw so there is not automatic encoding.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way of doing it using a Html helper.  It will convert your object into json and put it into a javascript variable.

HtmlHelper extension method

```
public static MvcHtmlString Jsonize(this HtmlHelper helper, string variableName, object obj)
{
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    str.Append("<script type='text/javascript'>");
    str.Append("var ");
    str.Append(variableName);
    str.Append("=");

    if (obj == null)
        str.Append("null");
    else
        str.Append(JsonHelper.Serialize(obj));

    str.Append(";");
    str.Append("</script>");
    return MvcHtmlString.Create(str.ToString());
}
```

The json serializer.  I'm using the DataContractJsonSerializer in this case.

```
public class JsonHelper
{
    public static string Serialize(object obj)
    {
        string json = null;
        DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(obj.GetType());
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            serializer.WriteObject(ms, obj);
            json = Encoding.Default.GetString(ms.ToArray());
        }
        return json;
    }
}
```

Once you have that done, you can just use it in your views to create a javascript variable that contains your object

```
@Html.Jsonize("data", ViewBag.SkinInfo.Data);
```

which will create something like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  var data = { your serialized object };
</script>
```